# Como faço para escrever o seguinte código SQL no Model do Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter

```
select count(situacao) as Qtde, sum(valorcausa) as Total_Valor_Causa 
from processo
where situacao = "Tramitando";
```

Answer (score 1):

Há varias formas de fazer isso, a que eu recomendo, por deixar o código mais organizado é essa:

```
$this->db->select('count(situacao) as Qtde, sum(valorcausa) as Total_Valor_Causa');
$this->db->where('situacao', 'Tramitando');
$query = $this->db->get('processo');
```

Outra forma é colocar a consulta inteira dentro do `query()`, dessa forma:

```
$this->db->query('select count(situacao) as Qtde, sum(valorcausa) as Total_Valor_Causa 
from processo where situacao = "Tramitando"')->get();
```

Recomendo a primeira pois você pode adicionar outros filtros na consulta, como:

```
$this->db->order_by('Total_Valor_Causa', 'DESC');
```

O código acima ira adionar uma ordenação pelo `Total_Valor_Causa`.

Para retornar apenas uma linha, você pode ordenar pelo `id` `desc`, e limitar a consulta a 1 registro, dessa forma o resultado será o último registro inserido;

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

[Mais informações](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado Dobrychtop, excelente resposta.

Comment: Saberia me dizer como faço para exibir somente o última linha de uma tabela, numa query escrita na classe model? obrigado

Comment: @Ramiro, adicionei a resposta uma forma de fazer isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez @Dobrychtop, deu certo, o problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer o que preciso, que é gerar um relatório que envolve duas tabelas, (A e B), sendo: Tabela A composta por (codprocesso, nprocesso), e a tabela B herda da A possuindo os compos (codandamento, descricao, fkcodprocesso). O que precisso fazer na classe Model é listar todos os processos, e o último andamento de cada 1 (um) dos processo existentes. Teria uma ideia de como fazer isso? Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Sempre procuro fazer o sql puro primeiro para depois passar pro CI, dessa forma ficou assim a query: 

select nprocesso, codandamento, dtandamento, descricao from processo
INNER JOIN andamento ON andamento.fkcodprocesso = processo.codprocesso
order by codandamento desc limit 1; 

Já até passei pro CI, essa query, contudo ela me retorna somente um registo, que é o último da tabela andamento, sendo o que eu quero exibir, é o último registro de cada fkcodprocesso (forein key) na tabela andamento. Entendeu?